# java script form validations error messge not working

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate forms data with javascript. It shows only one error message. it does not show `else if` part message, but it shows alert message! What happen in my code?

```
if (form.username.value == "") {
  alert('enter name');
  document.getElementById('namerror').innerHTML = "plese enter name";
}
else if (!form.username.value.match(mypattern)) {
  alert('only letters allowed');
  document.getElementById('namerror').innerHTML = "plese enter name"; //its not working
}
else {
  var x = form.username.value;
}
```

Comment: please add whole if/else if/else and a bit html.

Comment: Please add the whole part of your code

Comment: if(form.username.value == "") {
     alert('enter name');
   document.getElementById('namerror').innerHTML="plese enter name";
      
    }
 
 else if(!form.username.value.match(mypattern)){
 alert('only letters allowed');
 document.getElementById('namerror').innerHTML="plese enter name";
  
 }
 else{
  var x=form.username.value;
  
 }

Comment: which of the error massages is shown?

Comment: please provide the regex that you're matching the username value to;

Comment: provide html code of your form and username textbox (its name/id are important)